# Is the fault that I am trying to use an uninstalled font?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I have started to use the Tikz package. I am getting a “TeX capacity exceeded” fatal error message with something I am trying to do. See below,

```
****************************************
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\pgf@selectfontorig ->\pgf@selectfontorig 
                                          \nullfont 
l.40 };
****************************************
```

Is the fault that I am trying to use an uninstalled font?

Should I try to increase the TeX capacity somehow?

Extra Detail Follows, it is the code of the .tex file I am now using.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathtools}%objected to matrix stuff ISH
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization} 
\begin{document}
Hello Potential Help.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz \datavisualization [
scientific axes=clean,
x axis={attribute=time, ticks={tick unit=ms},
label={elapsed time}},
y axis={attribute=v, ticks={tick unit=m/s},
label={speed of disc}},
all axes=grid,
visualize as line]
data {
time, v
0, 0
1, 0.001
2, 0.002
3, 0.004
4, 0.0035
5, 0.0085
6, 0.0135
};
\end{tikzpicture}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could post a minimal code showing the error?

Comment: you have given so little context that it is hard to give help but it looks suspiciously like an infinite loop so increasing tex wouldn't help

Comment: `\tikz<code with no semicolon>;` is the same as `\begin{tikzpicture}<code with no semicolon>;\end{tikzpicture}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just delete  `\tikz` :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathtools}%objected to matrix stuff ISH
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization} 
\begin{document}
Hello Potential Help.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [
scientific axes=clean,
x axis={attribute=time, ticks={tick unit=ms},
label={elapsed time}},
y axis={attribute=v, ticks={tick unit=m/s},
label={speed of disc}},
all axes=grid,
visualize as line]
data {
time, v
0, 0
1, 0.001
2, 0.002
3, 0.004
4, 0.0035
5, 0.0085
6, 0.0135
};
\end{tikzpicture}.

\end{document}
```