# Tikz Graph: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, luatex

Here is my script(this is the example of pgfmanual.pdf by Till Tantau(terminal:texdoc tikz)):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,graphs,graphdrawing} 
\usegdlibrary{layered} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz [nodes={text height=.7em, text depth=.2em, draw=black!20, thick, fill=white, font=\footnotesize}, >={Stealth[round,sep]}, rounded corners, semithick] 
\graph [layered layout, level distance=1cm, sibling sep=.5em, sibling distance=1cm] {
"5th Edition" -> { "6th Edition", "PWB 1.0" };
"6th Edition" -> { "LSX" [>child anchor=45], "1 BSD", "Mini Unix", "Wollongong", "Interdata" }; "Interdata" -> { "Unix/TS 3.0", "PWB 2.0", "7th Edition" };
"7th Edition" -> { "8th Edition", "32V", "V7M", "Ultrix-11", "Xenix", "UniPlus+" };
"V7M" -> "Ultrix-11";
"8th Edition" -> "9th Edition";
"1 BSD" -> "2 BSD" -> "2.8 BSD" -> { "Ultrix-11", "2.9 BSD" };
"32V" -> "3 BSD" -> "4 BSD" -> "4.1 BSD" -> { "4.2 BSD", "2.8 BSD", "8th Edition" };
"4.2 BSD" -> { "4.3 BSD", "Ultrix-32" };
"PWB 1.0" -> { "PWB 1.2" -> "PWB 2.0", "USG 1.0" -> { "CB Unix 1", "USG 2.0" }};
"CB Unix 1" -> "CB Unix 2" -> "CB Unix 3" -> { "Unix/TS++", "PDP-11 Sys V" };
{ "USG 2.0" -> "USG 3.0", "PWB 2.0", "Unix/TS 1.0" } -> "Unix/TS 3.0";
{ "Unix/TS++", "CB Unix 3", "Unix/TS 3.0" } -> "TS 4.0" -> "System V.0" -> "System V.2" -> "System V.3"; }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The **error** is :

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls:24: TeX capacity
exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]. [...stem V.0" -> "System V.2" -> "System V.3"; }]
```

Comment: system: macOS 10.15.7 The latest MacTeX version. I tried it by LuaTeX and PdfLaTeX

Comment: I had this also. Edit your `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf.cnf`  (as root) and add `stack_size=500000` and see if this fixes it.

Comment: You haven't show the full error message. Here the same error is discussed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403423/is-the-fault-that-i-am-trying-to-use-an-uninstalled-font

Comment: the error is `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls:24: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=50000]. [...stem V.0" -> "System V.2" -> "System V.3"; }]` . I don't know why the stack size = 50000 rather than 500000 which I edited in `texmf.cnf`

Comment: when I detele `\tikz [nodes={text height=.7em, text depth=.2em, draw=black!20, thick, fill=white, font=\footnotesize}, >={Stealth[round,sep]}, rounded corners, semithick] `. It runs

Comment: But the figure is normal not fancy when delete the `\tikz`.

Comment: Can I use `\tikz` in the `tikzpicture` environment ?

Comment: I understand it！Just replace `\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz [nodes={text height=.7em,...` with `\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text height=.7em,...`. Just delete `\tikz`.

Comment: '''.        '''Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `\tikz` inside a `tikzpicture` environment. The manual uses only `\tikz`. You'll have to choose one.

This works for me using a `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,graphs,graphdrawing} 
\usegdlibrary{layered} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text height=.7em, text depth=.2em, draw=black!20, thick, fill=white, font=\footnotesize}, >={Stealth[round,sep]}, rounded corners, semithick] 
\graph [layered layout, level distance=1cm, sibling sep=.5em, sibling distance=1cm] {
"5th Edition" -> { "6th Edition", "PWB 1.0" };
"6th Edition" -> { "LSX" [>child anchor=45], "1 BSD", "Mini Unix", "Wollongong", "Interdata" }; "Interdata" -> { "Unix/TS 3.0", "PWB 2.0", "7th Edition" };
"7th Edition" -> { "8th Edition", "32V", "V7M", "Ultrix-11", "Xenix", "UniPlus+" };
"V7M" -> "Ultrix-11";
"8th Edition" -> "9th Edition";
"1 BSD" -> "2 BSD" -> "2.8 BSD" -> { "Ultrix-11", "2.9 BSD" };
"32V" -> "3 BSD" -> "4 BSD" -> "4.1 BSD" -> { "4.2 BSD", "2.8 BSD", "8th Edition" };
"4.2 BSD" -> { "4.3 BSD", "Ultrix-32" };
"PWB 1.0" -> { "PWB 1.2" -> "PWB 2.0", "USG 1.0" -> { "CB Unix 1", "USG 2.0" }};
"CB Unix 1" -> "CB Unix 2" -> "CB Unix 3" -> { "Unix/TS++", "PDP-11 Sys V" };
{ "USG 2.0" -> "USG 3.0", "PWB 2.0", "Unix/TS 1.0" } -> "Unix/TS 3.0";
{ "Unix/TS++", "CB Unix 3", "Unix/TS 3.0" } -> "TS 4.0" -> "System V.0" -> "System V.2" -> "System V.3";}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: """"""""""Thanks, I know it.